# Verbal constructions with "with" more common in AE than in BE

Tags: american-english

Is it correct, and safe to say, that -- *generally speaking* -- verbal constructions with "with' are *to a certain extent* more widely and commonly used in AE ***than*** in BE and other varieties of English ?

E. g.

Speak/talk with (as opposed to the shared speak/talk to);

visit with (=chat/converse with);

meet (up) with (originally chiefly AE);

get back with someone (as opposed to the shared "get back to");

stick with (as opposed to the shared "stick to");

check back with (as opposed to "check back to");

compare with (as opposed to the shared "compare to");

correspond with something (as opposed to the shared "correspond to");

interview with someone (as opposed to the shared "interview someone");

consult with someone (as opposed to the shared "consult someone");

conform with (as opposed to the shared "conform to");(...)

Comment: Whilst I don't *think* OP's proposition is true, I strongly disagree with the two closevotes cast so far. One claims it's Off Topic *proofreading*, which is frankly ridiculous. The other says it's *primarily opinion-based*, but it seems obvious to me that (in principle, at least) someone could investigate more thoroughly and establish the matter far more conclusively than my own relatively cursory checking of a few usages in the AmE/BrE corpuses of Google NGrams.

Comment: Please see also: my comment at OP's other recent post suggesting COCA/BNC.

Answer (score 3):

OP's proposition seems unlikely (at least in the *general* sense). Looking at the specific examples...

1: In both AmE and BrE, *speak/talk **with*** tends to imply a *conversation between equals*, whereas using ***to*** often implies a superior **telling** a subordinate something*.

2: Corpus-charts for *meet [with] someone* in Google Ngrams show that "with" occurs slightly more often in [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will%20meet%20with%20you,will%20meet%20you&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,will%20meet%20with%20you;,c0;.t1;,will%20meet%20you;,c0) than [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will%20meet%20with%20you,will%20meet%20you&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,will%20meet%20with%20you;,c0;.t1;,will%20meet%20you;,c0), but in both cases the form without a preposition is far more common. This obsevation is even more true with *visit [with] someone* (where "with" is virtually non-existent).

3: You might reasonably *get back **with** your girlfriend* if you'd previously broken up with her, but practically no-one says *"I'll get back with you"* when they mean *"I'll contact you later about this"*. Much the same applies to *"I'll check back with you"* (no-one says *"I'll check back **to** you"*).

4: Google Books offers *some* support for OP in that over the past couple of decades, [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stick%20to%20the%20plan,stick%20with%20the%20plan&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,stick%20to%20the%20plan;,c0;.t1;,stick%20with%20the%20plan;,c0) has taken up *sticking **with** the plan* slightly faster than [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stick%20to%20the%20plan,stick%20with%20the%20plan&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,stick%20to%20the%20plan;,c0;.t1;,stick%20with%20the%20plan;,c0) - but again, we all use *sticking **to** the plan* far more often. Most likely if "with" continues to rise, Brits will adopt it much the same as Americans. As usual, we'll just be a bit slower on the uptake.

Comment: Well, as far as I can gather, "visit with someone" doesn't mean the same as "visit someone", right? And so, I can just as well say that I of late visited with my aunt over the phone, that I visited with my cousin on Skype a couple days ago, that I visited on various occasions with my step uncle by email, and that the other day I dropped by and visited with my mother most of the afternoon, can't I?

Comment: @Nourished Gourmet: No, you are completely mistaken. Firstly, you can't normally "visit" anyone by phone or on Skype (the verb strongly implies *meeting **in person***). Secondly, on the (relatively rare) occasions when someone says something like *"The doctor will visit with you tomorrow"*, they always mean exactly the same thing as the vastly more common version *without* the word "with".

Comment: ...I would strongly suggest you ask any future questions like this on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), since it seems you aren't very familiar with standard usages. It's a more suitable site for people who need help with the basics.

Comment: Once again I have to disagree with you. It isn't "visit someone" that is involved here, but the colloquial idiom "visit with" that means "converse/chat with" and can be used in each and every one of the contexts specified in my previous comment. ;)

Comment: I was wondering whether you would mind and consider what I found here and there on the net as sourced examples such usages of "visit with". Hope you will enjoy each and every one of them: "I actually talked to Josh on Saturday amd visited with him over the phone." http://espn.go.com/dallas/nfl/story/_/id/8756221/josh-brent-dallas-cowboys-surprised-jerry-jones-jason-garrett-attending-game

Comment: "I haven't actually met with Dr. Downing for a counseling section but actually met with him over the phone." http://www.wellness.com/dir/6021387/marriage--family-therapist/ca/fullerton/dr-kevin-downing-turning-point-counseling-phd-mft; Danny wasn't there but I visited with him over the phone." http://www.thesmokering.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11720&view=next&sid=c452d9ef4ce566675ade559def470fee; "I visited with him online, and enjoyed reading his posts." http://www.memorialobituaries.com/memorials/memgb.cgi?action=Guestbook&memid=172133&clientid=baue&decedent=++

Comment: "I know I visited with him by email..." http://investorshub.advfn.com/boards/read_msg.aspx?message_id=77693546; "...and I have visited with him via email." http://archiver.rootsweb.ancestry.com/th/read/FOSTER/2002-03/1015595075

Comment: "His family have already visited with him via the webcam" http://www.fofrescue.org/about-us/past-residents-rest-peace/; "but we visited with him via text messages." http://billssundaysuppers.blogspot.fr/2013_12_01_archive.html; "...visited with my late grandmother in a priceless, sweet, eight hour sleep." https://mobile.twitter.com/Stoney_Official/status/389371703023132672?screen_name=Stoney_Official. Do you have enough? Are you replenished alright?  Or should I increase that list with further talking examples? Just tell, and I will mind and do as I am told. ;)

Comment: Nourished Gourmet, speak/talk *with*, meet *with* and visit *with* are not exactly in common use, in the UK. In all of them, the word *with* is superfluous. If these are used at all, they are rare. They are much more common in American English.

Comment: @Nourished Gourmet: I realise you can find a *few* instances of "visit with", but I think you're mistaken in assuming this is a "normal, valid" US usage that means something different to the prepositionless version. It's just non-standard phrasing from people who often have limited language skills and therefore would not be likely to come out with a more "grammatical" form such as *"I **interacted** with him over the phone"*. You won't find many if any examples of competent writers *meeting* via an audio-only link-up - but I accept that with Skype (incl. *video*) it's just about credible.

Comment: @Tristanr I cannot more than agree with you on that. That's what I always have been trying to point out through the OP.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To push things a little further on that particular point, I would not be any surprised either to hear "I visited with the spirit of my great-great grandfather through a psychic named Angel" coming out of an American mouth. Obviously, the colloquial expression "visit with" has a very specific meaning in AE, as it implies a significant amount of time spent talking with each other, but also a certain congeniality, or proximity, or familiarity, or even just a good catchup between the participants. ;)

Comment: @Nourished: Well, maybe *you* "would not be **any** surprised **either**" to hear such things. But I'm reasonably familiar with most differences between "standard" AmE and BrE, and I'd have to say that much of your phrasing here sounds at the very least "non-standard" to me. I can't very well say it's "incorrect" though - if you're a native speaker and that's how you speak/write, obviously from your point of view your usages are "correct".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sounds like you find some fault in my writing "not be any surprised", don't you? Well, I might say just as well "not be surprised at all, or in the least" if either of these sound any more acceptable to your ears. It's just that to my perspective "any" sounds a bit more colloquial, and that exactly is the way I want to sound in such informal prose as posts, emails, etc.  Now, to get back to "visit" and get your mind at ease once and for all, I thought you might want to consider clicking the link that'll appear in my next post and checking out for yourself what it's all about. ;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.fr/2012/10/visiting.html

Comment: @Nourished: If you like. I get the impression that blogger isn't exactly an authority on general usage, and many of the comments make the point that *visit with* is regional/dialectal/old-fashioned. I myself would certainly accept forms like *"We visited for several hours"*, with the proviso that this isn't a particularly *current* usage to me (it sounds almost Victorian). But I do note that Americans seem to have taken up that usage more in recent decades.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Glad to hear you say that! ;)