# Verbal constructions with "on" in colloquial AE

Tags: american-english, transatlantic-differences

Are verbal constructions with "on" somewhat more typical of AE than BE?

e.g. beat (up) on someone, miss out on something, pass up on something, check (up) on something, catch up on something, someone, etc.

Comment: I suggest the OP do a quick study of stats from the COCA and BNC.

Comment: Closers, how is this opinion based? I think it is about as data based as possible. (it might be difficult for someone to have good experience with both Ame and BrE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yet again](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150910/verbal-constructions-with-with-more-common-in-ae-than-in-be), I don't understand the "POB" closevotes here.

The specific usage *beat up **on** someone* is very much an Americanism (it's about [five times more common in AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beat%20up%20on%20him&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,beat%20up%20on%20him;,c0) than it is in [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beat%20up%20on%20him&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,beat%20up%20on%20him;,c0)). But as with OP's previous question, I think it's important to note that *beat someone up* [is far more common everywhere.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beat%20up%20on%20him,beat%20him%20up&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,beat%20up%20on%20him;,c0;.t1;,beat%20him%20up;,c0)

To *catch up **on*** (usually, *something* rather than *someone*) is a relatively uncommon usage everywhere (it's often for learning about the latest developments in some subject). Both Brits and Americans normally *catch up **with** a person* when they mean they will *meet* with them soon.

I've no reason to suppose Americans are any more likely than Brits to [check **up** on someone](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=check%20up%20on%20him,check%20on%20him&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,check%20up%20on%20him;,c0;.t1;,check%20on%20him;,c0). As that NGran shows, we all use the "up" version sometimes (but usually we *don't*).

Comment: What I meant in the OP -- and that I clarified just recently -- is "check (up) on something" in the sense of "examine so as to determine accuracy, quality, or condition", which is seldom used in BE -- or at least not as commonly used in AE. Anyone to agree on that?

Comment: @Nourished Gourmet: I know what you meant. Not that it makes any difference if we consider the more figurative usage where *checking [up] on someone* means finding out what they're up to, or making sure they're okay. There's no significant US/UK divide on the usage. I simply chose the *someone* version because it's easier to chart in NGrams using a target string that's more likely to match the usage we're interested in, with less "false positive" irrelevant matches.

Comment: *Beat up on* must be an Americanism. It's not used in the UK. It is also jarring and extremely awkward from a British perspective.

Comment: @Tristan: I know what you mean. Most "Americanisms" don't really bother me (I just think sometimes they use rather odd turns of phrase). But *beat up **on** someone* really jars with me too - if it turns up in a film, for instance, I invariably think *"That's totally ungrammatical. The extra preposition is just plain *wrong* there"*.